# Past Tense of “I am looking for”

Tags: past-tense

What is the past tense of

> I am looking for shirts.

Is it "I was looking for shirts"?

Would I correctly say

> I was looking for dark shaded semi-formal shirts.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @CopperKettle So is this sentence correct "I said I was looking for dark shaded semi-formal shirts."

Comment: Yes, Gopesh, perfectly correct.

Comment: Yes. Indeed it is.

Comment: The pleasure is mine. (0:

Answer (score 3):

The past tense of "I am looking for Shirts" is "I was looking for Shirts".

Usage : I said **I was looking for** dark-colored semi-formal shirts

Comment: With your more complicated sentence, I would definitely use dark-colored rather than dark shaded.  A different arrangement might be, "I was looking for semi-formal shirts *in dark shades*."  It's not important for your ultimate question of verb conjugation, but the original "dark shaded" version really sounds awkward to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

Auxiliary "be", "have", and "do" are conjugated normally while the participle/infinitive used in the construction is left as is.

> I **did** *get* into a fight.
>
> You **had** *fidgeted* in class.
>
> The student **was** *being* naughty.
>
> He **does** *indeed* do his chores.

Thus

> I **was** looking for dark shaded semi-formal shirts.

is correct, because you are trying to look for past tense.